# Outlook custom buttons in ribbon

Tags: vba, outlook, ribbon

I can use custum ui editor for Excel and Word VBA projects to add custom buttons on the ribbon with XML.

I have an Outlook-project (VBAProject.otm) and would like to do the same thing, to add buttons to the ribbon so when I'm deploying the custom buttons move with it.

I don't wont to use VSTO, only VBA.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Unlike other Office applications, in Outlook VBA macros can't be used for customizing the ribbon UI. You need to develop a COM add-in (for example, a VSTO based one). Take a look at the following articles:

[Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Tab by Using the Ribbon Designer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386104.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

[Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Tab by Using Ribbon XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942955.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

The Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) is described in depth in the following series of articles:

[Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

[Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

[Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

---

[Full Credit to This Site](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b23c6872-69b9-4238-b27e-f5fef426003f/outlook-ribbon-custom-button?forum=outlookdev)